# Raid 0 (OS) + SSD Cache, what are performances like compared to pure SSD (OS)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, cache, raid-0

I'm considering a RAID 0 setup with an SSD cache drive. Will I see a noticeable difference in speed with the SSD cache drive, will this even work?

No I will not install the OS on the SSD. I'd prefer to avoid micro management, I need the space of my spinners.

Comment: How are you planning on using the SSD as a cache?  Intel RST?  Or some other solution?

Comment: Planning on using Crucial's Adrenaline ssd cache with dataplex software.

Comment: While I haven't used dataplex personally, this has some limitations.  According to the [system requirements](http://www.nvelo.com/support/dataplex/system-requirements), you have to use MBR if you're making the boot drive the target, meaning you can't use UEFI and GPT partitions, it's Win7 only, etc.